# Fingerprint authentication of user in Angular | Python

Tags: javascript, angular, authentication, fingerprint, biometrics

I need to achieve fingerprint authentication of the user using a fingerprint machine. Basically, I want to detect a student fingerprint of a user in an application running in a browser using Angular 10+, using the client as Angular and Python, Django as the backend.

Visited package, they are supporting for native apps, but I need to authenticate the user in web application.

Discovered packages:

- ng device detector
- camsunit

but didn't help me to achieve the task.

Need help in this regards.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why wasn't `camsunit` helpful, can highlight a bit more? As per their website you should be able to do it for their hardware. What hardware are you using? Did you try https://github.com/marcellkiss/angular-webauthn-example? Their [demo](https://marcellkiss.github.io/angular-webauthn-example/) is pretty cool and I could get it checked with MacBook Pro touch ID.

Comment: I didn't try this https://github.com/marcellkiss/angular-webauthn-example. I'll get back to you after try the link.

Comment: @NagarajTantri By going through the given link I came through the question that how can we read a laptop fingerprint in angular web application?

Comment: they are using https://webauthn.io, which is the new spec for providing auth via fingerprint. That repo that is pasted should have that link.